# How can I insert 0 and 1 values in the sql as bit datatype

Tags: asp.net

I created a table like
Create table t(name varchar(50),age int,sex bit)
This is the table when I insert values in the table...like
Insert into t values('rakesh',28,1)
It displays rakesh 28 true
I need to store 1or 0 values in the database which is having data type as bit...

Comment: `bit` is in C# represented as `bool` so if it's returning `true` then it's ok

Answer (score 0):

In binary, a one equals TRUE and a zero equals FALSE. If you'd like to display 1 or 0 use something like this:

```
int i = sex ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said. 1and true are equivalent values, and so the issue you raise is more on the display of a bit as an int.

If you are displaying the data with SQL, you can try to cast the value. Something like :

```
select cast(sex as smallint) as sex
```